# POS order product total

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

my goal is to add a field in product form view that will show how many time this product was bought with POS. really stuck with this one and would be nice to have an idea how to do this.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    pos_product_order_total = fields.Char(
        string='Product POS Orders', compute='_product_pos_orders')

    def _product_pos_orders(self):
        Order = self.env['pos.order']
        for product in self:
            domain = [('product_id', '=', product.id)]
            for o in Order.search(domain):
                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    pos_product_order_total = fields.Char(
        string='Product POS Orders', compute='_product_pos_orders')

    def _product_pos_orders(self):
        OrderLine = self.env['pos.order.line']
        for product in self:
            domain = [('product_id', '=', product.id)]
            product.pos_product_order_total = sum(OrderLine.search(domain).mapped('qty'))
```